# How do I add words from an text file to an array i created?

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

So I have this text file that has a bunch of single line words that I want to add to my array. But somehow the JUnit tests keep failing. Any ideas on how I can fix this? The variable numberOfWords has already been declared and assigned a value.

```
public void addWordsToArray(String fileName) {
    loadWords(fileName); 

    String[] words = new String[numberOfWords];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) {
        words[i] = iter.next(); } }
```

-----The Full File is as Below. I will Also share the Tests-------------

```
public class Words {

ArrayList<String> wordList; // All the words
Iterator<String> iter; // iterator for the wordlist
int numberOfWords; // number of words in the file

String[] words; // this array holds your words

public Words() {
    wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    // iter = wordList.iterator();
}

/**
 * This method loads the words from a given file
 * 
 * @param fileName
 *            input file name
 */
private void loadWords(String fileName) {
    wordList.clear();
    numberOfWords = 0;
    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            wordList.add(line.toLowerCase());
            count++;
        }

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();
        numberOfWords = count;
        iter = wordList.iterator();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
    }
}

public String getWord(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= numberOfWords) {
        return null;
    }
    return words[index];
}

/**
 * This method adds all the words to an array called words
 * 
 * variable numberOfWords is already declared and has value and contains number
 * of words
 * 
 * @param fileName:
 *            input file name
 */
public void addWordsToArray(String fileName) {
    loadWords(fileName); // DO NOT CHANGE

    String[] words = new String[numberOfWords];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) {
        words[i] = iter.next();

        // variable numberOfWords has the number of words
    // TODO
    // String[] words has been declared. Now instantiate the array to the words
    // array size is equal to the number of words

    }
    // words = null;
    // TO DO
    /**
     * Calling iter.next() will return the next word in the file. For examples
     * String w = iter.next(); iter.next() always gives a next word
     */

    // TO DO
    // Add all word into the array words

}

/**
 * 
 * @param word:
 *            input
 * @return true if the given word exits in the words array. False otherwise
 */
public boolean contains(String word) {
    for (String wordz : wordList) {
        if (wordz.contains(word)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param sentence:
 *            input sentence
 * @return true if every word in the sentence exists in your words array. False
 *         otherwise.
 */
public boolean containsSentence(String sentence) {
    String[] sp = sentence.split(" ");
    for (String wordz : wordList) {
        if (wordz.equals(sp)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * reverse a sentence
 * 
 * @param sentence:
 *            input sentence
 * @return reversed sentence. For example: input: "i love you" return: "you love
 *         i" (hint: trim leading and trailing spaces")
 */
public String reverseSentence(String sentence) {
    // if(sentence == null || sentence.length()==0) {
    // return sentence;
    // }
    String[] sp = sentence.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = sp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(sp[i]);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();

}

/**
 * 
 * @param word:
 *            input word
 * @return the number of occurrences of the word . If the word does not exist,
 *         return 0
 */
public int count(String word) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String wordz : wordList) {
        if (wordz.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
            count++;
            // return count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param word1:
 *            input word
 * @param word2:
 *            input word
 * @return true if all letters from word1 exist in word2, and all letters from
 *         word2 exist in word1.
 */
public boolean anagram(String word1, String word2) {
    String sw1 = word1.replaceAll("\\s", "");

    String sw2 = word2.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    boolean check = true;
    char[] w1 = sw1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] w2 = sw2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(w1);
    Arrays.sort(w2);

    if (sw1.length() != sw2.length()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        check = Arrays.equals(w1, w2);

    }
    if (check) {
        return true;
    } else

        return false;

}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @param word:
 *            input word
 * @param fileName:
 *            input file name
 * 
 *            PRINT all words that are the anagrams to the word input within
 *            words array
 * 
 */
public void findAnagram(String word, String fileName) {
    addWordsToArray(fileName); // DO NOT CHANGE

}} 

 }
```

------The Tests are: ------------

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import words.Words;

public class PublicTests {

Words w; 
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    w = new Words();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void testaddWordsToArray1() {
    w.addWordsToArray("common_names.txt");
    String result = w.getWord(4);
    String expected = "william";
    assertEquals(expected,result);
}

@Test
public void testaddWordsToArray2() {
    w.addWordsToArray("names.txt");
    String result = w.getWord(2);
    String expected = "akbar";
    assertEquals(expected,result);
}


@Test
public void testContains1() {
    w.addWordsToArray("names.txt");
    boolean result = w.contains("akbar");
    assertTrue(result);
}


@Test
public void testContains2() {
    w.addWordsToArray("names.txt");
    boolean result = w.contains("administration");
    assertFalse(result);
}


@Test
public void testContains3() {
    w.addWordsToArray("1000words.txt");
    boolean result = w.contains("administration");
    assertTrue(result);
}


@Test
public void testContainsSentence1() {
    w.addWordsToArray("1000words.txt");
    boolean result = w.containsSentence("i buy book");
    assertTrue(result);
}

@Test
public void testContainsSentence2() {
    w.addWordsToArray("1000words.txt");
    boolean result = w.containsSentence("i love you");
    assertTrue(result);
}

@Test
public void testContainsSentence3() {
    w.addWordsToArray("1000words.txt");
    boolean result = w.containsSentence("she loves me");
    assertFalse(result);
}


@Test
public void testReverseSentence1() {
    String result = w.reverseSentence("i love you");
    String expected = "you love i";
    assertEquals(expected, result);
}

@Test
public void testReverseSentence2() {
    String result = w.reverseSentence("maria");
    String expected = "maria";
    assertEquals(expected, result);
}

@Test
public void testReverseSentence3() {
    String result = w.reverseSentence("cybertek school");
    String expected = "school cybertek";
    assertEquals(expected, result);
}


@Test
public void testCount1() {
    w.addWordsToArray("test1.txt");
    int result = w.count("abcd");
    int expected = 2;
    assertEquals(expected,result);
}

@Test
public void testCount2() {
    w.addWordsToArray("test1.txt");
    int result = w.count("bbcc");
    int expected = 1;
    assertEquals(expected,result);
}

@Test
public void testCount3() {
    w.addWordsToArray("names.txt");
    int result = w.count("trump");
    int expected = 0;
    assertEquals(expected,result);
}


@Test
public void testAnagram1() {
    boolean result = w.anagram("abcd", "bcda");
    assertTrue(result);
}
@Test
public void testAnagram2() {
    boolean result = w.anagram("bbd", "ddb");
    assertTrue(result);
}

@Test
public void testAnagram3() {
    boolean result = w.anagram("abcd", "aadb");
    assertFalse(result);
}


@Test
public void testFindAnagram1() throws Exception, Throwable{
    runProgramWithInput("abcd", "test1.txt");
}


@Test
public void testFindAnagram2() throws Exception, Throwable{
    runProgramWithInput("save", "1000words.txt");
}



/**
 * Executes a run of the OrdersProcessor program by reading the data
 * in the specified file using input redirection.  The file inputFileName
 * has the item's data file, whether multiple threads will be used,
 * number of orders, base file name for the orders, and the 
 * result file name.
 * 
 * @param inputFilename
 * @throws Exception
 * @throws Throwable
 */
private void runProgramWithInput(String word, String inputFilename) throws Exception, Throwable {

    /* Retrieving the name of the results file */

    String filename="";
    int i = inputFilename.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (i > 0) {
        filename = inputFilename.substring(0,i);
    }

    String resultsFilename = filename + "_out.txt";
    String officialResultsFilename = filename + "_expected.txt";

    /* Deleting results file (in case it exists) */
    File file = new File(resultsFilename);
    file.delete();

    /* Actual execution of the test by using input redirection and calling 
    /* OrdersProcessor.main(null) */
    TestingSupport.redirectStandardInputTo(inputFilename);
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = TestingSupport.redirectStandardOutputToByteArrayStream();

    w.findAnagram(word, inputFilename);

    String output = b.toString();
    TestingSupport.writeToFile(resultsFilename, output);

    /* Checking if we got the right results */
    assertTrue(TestingSupport.sameContents(resultsFilename, officialResultsFilename));
}


   }
```

-.------

Comment: you left a lot out please include the entire function/file.
what does loadWords() do?
where is numberOfWords and iter declared?

Comment: What is the error you are getting while executing JUnit test cases? and what exactly is loadWords function doing?also, how iter is getting its values? Please include all the necessary information for us to look into it

Comment: @scigs like this?

Answer (score 1):

As @scigs's comment points out, you left a lot out here. I'm going to assume you're just trying to load all the words in the file into an array (and that there is one word per line). You can do this with a `Scanner`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    words.add(scanner.nextLine().trim());
}
```

You can also use Apache Commons `commons-io` library for its `IOUtils` class. The `IOUtils.readLines()` method does pretty much what the block of code above does, but is obviously more convenient/more compact to use:

```
List<String> words = IOUtils.readLines(new FileInputStream(filename));
```

Comment: I tried that, and it now says "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException"

Answer (score 0):

```
words = new String[numberOfWords];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) {
        words[i]=iter.next();
```

worked perfectly. thanks guys!